# How can i change date format in Jquery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used Jquery datepicker. But i need to change the date format from ***dd-mm-yy*** to ***yy-mm-dd***. (Also date highlight function used)

```js
var dates = ['03-03-2017', '03-10-2017', '03-25-2017'];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  //defaultDate: new Date('03/10/2017'), // this line is for testing
  beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});

function highlightDays(date) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
      return [true, 'highlight'];
    }
  }
  return [true, ''];
}
```

```css
td.highlight>a {
  background: #E50104!important;
  color: #fff!important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: You have a `dateFormat` property right in your code...?

Comment: Tried - dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' -but not working

Comment: Yes it does - I just tried changing it in your snippet to test it.

Comment: It is working. Check my answer. I have added working snippet there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple. Just change `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',` to `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'`,

```js
var dates = ['03-03-2017', '03-10-2017', '03-25-2017'];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    //defaultDate: new Date('03/10/2017'), // this line is for testing
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

```css
td.highlight > a {
 background: #E50104!important;
 color: #fff!important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is:

```
var dates = ["03-03-2017', '03-10-2017', '03-25-2017"]

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```